# ¿Como puedo obtener el password de un usuario de windows en java?

Tags: java, windows

Ya he probado con la clase `System` pero con dicha clase solo puedo obtener el usuario de la siguiente forma:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name"));
```

ahora lo que necesito es obtener el `password`, he intentado buscar un comando para `cmd` pero al parecer no existe. Pueden ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Para entender mejor tu pregunta coloca mas codigo de como capturas `user.name`

Comment: Solo es necesaria la linea System.getProperty("user.name"); eso devuele un String con el nombre del usuario.

Comment: No se puede, la contraseña del usuario sólo la sabe él, ni siquiera el sistema la sabe, realmente

Comment: Vale muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede, el sistema operativo no almacena la contraseña, probablemente utilice algun tipo de certificado, cifrado, huella...

Esto es lo que te permite obtener `System.getProperty(string)`

```
Key                 Meaning
"file.separator"    Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.
"java.class.path"   Path used to find directories and JAR archives containing class files. Elements of the class path are separated by a platform-specific character specified in the path.separator property.
"java.home"         Installation directory for Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
"java.vendor"       JRE vendor name
"java.vendor.url"   JRE vendor URL
"java.version"      JRE version number
"line.separator"    Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files
"os.arch"           Operating system architecture
"os.name"           Operating system name
"os.version"        Operating system version
"path.separator"    Path separator character used in java.class.path
"user.dir"          User working directory
"user.home"         User home directory
"user.name"         User account name
```

[Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)